# How to cycle through a defined list of elements

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a large dictionary of lists which is generated dynamically as part of a larger python program. This is an example of what the dictionary looks like

```py
params = {
'output': ['quantity_tot_1m', 'quantity_tot_3m', 'quantity_tot_6m',
'quantity_tot_12m', 'quantity_tot_full', 'cost_tot_1m', 'cost_tot_3m', 'cost_tot_6m', 'cost_tot_12m', 'cost_tot_full', 'selling_tot_1m', 
'selling_tot_3m', 'selling_tot_6m', 'selling_tot_12m', 'selling_tot_full', 'profit_tot_1m', 'profit_tot_3m', 'profit_tot_6m', 'profit_tot_12m', 'profit_tot_full'], 
'agg_types': ['By SKU - 01 Month','By SKU - 03 Months','By SKU - 06 Months','By SKU - 12 Months']
}
```

I need assistance being able to cycle over these lists

I have tried the below

```py
from jinjasql import JinjaSql
j = JinjaSql(param_style='pyformat')

QUERY_TEMPLATE = """
{% set mix_agg = agg_types|replace("[","")|replace("]","") %}
{% set mix_agg2 = cycler(mix_agg) %}
{% for o in output %}
ROUND(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN agg_type = '{{ mix_agg2.next() | sqlsafe }}' THEN profit_tot ELSE 0 END ) AS NUMERIC),2) AS {{o | sqlsafe}} {% endfor%}
"""

query, bind_params = j.prepare_query(QUERY_TEMPLATE, params)
print(query)
```

This doesn't cycle over the list, it merely outputs the list as is. Of course I cannot explicitly type the list into the cycler because this has to be dynamic.

Perhaps a `cycler()` isn't the best approach but I need an output like the below:

```sql
ROUND(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN agg_type = 'By SKU - 01 Month' THEN profit_tot ELSE 0 END ) AS NUMERIC),2) AS profit_tot_1m,

ROUND(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN agg_type = 'By SKU - 03 Months' THEN profit_tot ELSE 0 END ) AS NUMERIC),2) AS profit_tot_3m,

ROUND(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN agg_type = 'By SKU - 06 Months' THEN profit_tot ELSE 0 END ) AS NUMERIC),2) AS profit_tot_6m,

ROUND(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN agg_type = 'By SKU - 12 Months' THEN profit_tot ELSE 0 END ) AS NUMERIC),2) AS profit_tot_12m
```

not like this:

```sql
ROUND(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN agg_type = 'By SKU - 01 Month', 'By SKU - 03 Months', 'By SKU - 06 Months', 'By SKU - 12 Months' THEN profit_tot ELSE 0 END ) AS NUMERIC),2) AS profit_tot_1m,

ROUND(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN agg_type = 'By SKU - 01 Month', 'By SKU - 03 Months', 'By SKU - 06 Months', 'By SKU - 12 Months' THEN profit_tot ELSE 0 END ) AS NUMERIC),2) AS profit_tot_3m,

ROUND(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN agg_type = 'By SKU - 01 Month', 'By SKU - 03 Months', 'By SKU - 06 Months', 'By SKU - 12 Months' THEN profit_tot ELSE 0 END ) AS NUMERIC),2) AS profit_tot_6m,
 
ROUND(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN agg_type = 'By SKU - 01 Month', 'By SKU - 03 Months', 'By SKU - 06 Months', 'By SKU - 12 Months' THEN profit_tot ELSE 0 END ) AS NUMERIC),2) AS profit_tot_12m
```

There are a total of 20 output columns `{{o | sqlsafe}}`

Comment: Where are the items in `params` referenced in `QUERY_TEMPLATE`? Or is that not actually relevant to your question? Looking at the "I need an output like below" part oft he question, it looks like you're more interested in how to iterate over the content of `agg_types`...

Comment: Hi @larsks, the actual params dictionary is large. It has about 30 different keys. The params dict I've put here is merely an example of what it looks like once it is generated. `prepare_query()` expects 2 arguments. I will edit the question and insert the 2 lists into the dictionary for better understanding

Comment: I've edited the question so that the params dict uses the lists I previously defined as variables. Hope it makes more sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
{% set mix_agg = agg_types|replace("[","")|replace("]","") %}
```

turns what was an array type into a string which just makes it harder to use later, and is probably not what you want.

The line

```
{% set mix_agg2 = cycler(mix_agg) %}
```

then creates a cycler with a single sting to cycle through - so it will repeatadly return this single string.

To cycle through an array use the python `*` operator - which turns an array into function arguments:

```
{% set mix_agg2 = cycler(*agg_types) %}
```

Putting this together we have:

```
QUERY_TEMPLATE = """
{% set mix_agg2 = cycler(*agg_types) %}
{% for o in output %}
ROUND(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN agg_type = '{{ mix_agg2.next() | sqlsafe }}' THEN profit_tot ELSE 0 END ) AS NUMERIC),2) AS {{o | sqlsafe}}
{% endfor %}
"""
```

Furthermore: `output` includes `_tot_full` which is missing from `agg_types`. You can fix this by adding it to `agg_types` or removing it from `output` when they are defined, or adding a `if` to skip it in the loop.

Comment: Hi @Kim, this works. Thank you so much. Regarding `tot_full` I've got an `{% if %}` statement which handles it perfectly. it will depend on the table itself how it's handled. So for this table specifically the if statement looks like this `{%- if o.endswith('full') %} 
{% if  table == 'pd_aggregate' %}0 {{o | sqlsafe}}{% if not loop.last %},{%- endif %}
{% else %}...` 

I did not know about the `*`... that will come in so handy in future projects. Thanks again